# SQL Query for If not null,then update or else keep the same data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am having a table which has about 17 fields. I need to perform frequent updates in this table. But the issue is each time I may be updating only a few fields. Whats the best way to write a query for updating in such a scenario? I am looking for an option in which the value gets updated only if it is not null.

For example I have four fields in database Say A,B,C,D. User updates the value of say D. All other values remains the same. So I want an update query which updates only the value of D keeping the others unaltered. SO if i put a,b and c as null and d with the value supplied by user I want to write an update query which only updates the value of d as a,b and c is null.
MsSQL 2012 is my database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be something like this

```
Update T
SET A = CASE WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN 'Value' ELSE A END,
    B = CASE WHEN B IS NOT NULL THEN 'Value' ELSE B END,
    C = CASE WHEN C IS NOT NULL THEN 'Value' ELSE C END
    D = CASE WHEN D IS NOT NULL THEN 'Value' ELSE D END
FROM Table1 T
```

Comment: what will happen when ELSE A ? null value will be updated or existing value will be kept?

Comment: Else A means Existing value will be kept - @Selva

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling this from an application, the easiest way is to just run the query that you want:

```
update t
    set d = @d
    where id = @id;
```

If you want a generic statement, then you can use:

```
update t
    set a = coalesce(@a, a),
        b = coalesce(@b, b),
        c = coalesce(@c, c),
        d = coalesce(@d, d)
    where id = @id;
```

Comment: If the parameters are of `int` type than they're passed as `0` instead of `null`. How to resolve this isssue?

Comment: @HarshilDoshi . . . `int` can be passed in as `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use nullable parameters along with [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.T_Update 
    @ID INT,
    @A VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @B VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @C VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @D VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  dbo.T
    SET     A = ISNULL(@A, A),
            B = ISNULL(@B, B)
            C = ISNULL(@C, C)
            D = ISNULL(@D, D)
    WHERE   ID = @ID;

END
```

Then you only need to pass the columns you need to update. e.g.

```
EXECUTE dbo.T_Update @ID = 1, @D = 'Test';
```

Or alternatively you can just pass `NULL`:

```
EXECUTE dbo.T_Update 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Test';
```

Comment: what will happen when ISNULL means(@A,A)? null value will be updated or existing value will be kept?